# TFS build failures due to CSPack not finding files

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, tfs, azure

I'm using TFS to build an Azure project including an ASP.NET MVC 3 web role.

Currently my builds are failing with the following error:-

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Cloud
>   Service\1.0\Visual Studio
>   10.0\Microsoft.CloudService.targets (202): Could not find a part of the
>   path...

Followed by a path to a file called "WaIISHost.exe.config" under "{AzureProject}\roles\{WebRole}\x64\".

I've checked on the build server, and indeed this file does not exist. In fact, the entire "{webRole}\x64\" directory does not appear to have been created. The directory is also not created when I build on my own machine. I created a fresh Azure project with the wizard (with an MVC 2 web role also created by the wizard) and the directory wasn't created for that either.

Line 202 in Microsoft.CloudService.targets appears to be invoking the CSPack utility - which presumably is attempting to package the WebRole for deployment. It expects files in the "...\x64" directory and isn't finding them - hence the build failure.

Despite the "missing" files, I can build and publish from my own machine. I only get errors on the build server.

- Any idea why the "...\x64" directory
  is not being created for my web role?
- Is it possible to instruct CSPack to
  not look for these files?
- What relies on CSPack having done its job during the build? If I delete the CSPack invocation from the .targets file, will there be any consequences?

**Edit**

The part of the log that's failling is:-

```
ModelFile            is  (TaskId:310)
OutputDirectory      is C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Binaries\GBC.Web.Azure.csx\ (TaskId:311)
PackRoles            is C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Sources\GBC\GBC.Web.Azure\obj\Release\GBC.Web.Site\, Name=GBC.Web.Site, EntryPoint=GBC.Web.Site.dll, SourceDir=C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Sources\GBC\GBC.Web.Site\ (TaskId:312)
RoleProperties       is GBC.Web.Site, EntryPoint=GBC.Web.Site.dll, TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0 (TaskId:313)
ServiceDefinitionCopy is ServiceDefinition.build.csdef (TaskId:314)
ServiceConfigurationCopy is C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Binaries\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg (TaskId:315)
Calling ServicePack (TaskId:316)
Using "CSPack" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Azure SDK\v1.4\bin\Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.dll".
Task "CSPack" (TaskId:317)
Searching for imported module Diagnostics at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Azure SDK\v1.4\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\Diagnostics.csplugin... (TaskId:317)
Copying 'C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Sources\GBC\GBC.Web.Azure\obj\Release\GBC.Web.Site\' to C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Binaries\GBC.Web.Azure.csx\roles\GBC.Web.Site\approot... (TaskId:317)
Copying 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Azure SDK\v1.4\bin\runtimes\base\x86' to C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Binaries\GBC.Web.Azure.csx\roles\GBC.Web.Site\base\x86... (TaskId:317)
Copying 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Azure SDK\v1.4\bin\runtimes\diagnostics\x86' to C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Binaries\GBC.Web.Azure.csx\roles\GBC.Web.Site\diagnostics\x86... (TaskId:317)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Cloud Service\1.0\Visual Studio 10.0\Microsoft.CloudService.targets(202,5): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Binaries\GBC.Web.Azure.csx\roles\GBC.Web.Site\base\x64\WaIISHost.exe.config'. [C:\Builds\2\GBC\GBC - CI Build\Sources\GBC\GBC.Web.Azure\GBC.Web.Azure.ccproj]
Done executing task "CSPack" -- FAILED. (TaskId:317)
```

Looks like it's a problem with CSPack - it's copying the files in from Program Files...\bin\runtimes\base\x86, but not from ...\x64, then it's expecting something in the target ...\x64 directory. Possibly something to do with the way CSPack is configured? Definitely looks like it's not MSBuild's job to be creating those files.

Comment: Do you have the Azure tools installed on your build machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it.

If you're trying to build azure projects on a server and you're following the instructions at:- http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/05/building-azure-solutions-on-your-build.html - make sure that if your server is 64-bit you copy the files off a 64-bit machine. If you've got the 32-bit SDK on a 64-bit machine, it won't like that!

Alternately, you can use the web platform installer to install the Azure SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the detailed MSBuild output and post it (option for your buildtype)?

Typically when folders aren't created it's because either a configuration issue or lack of permissions.

MS does a decent job of breaking down what CSPack does [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432988.aspx).

Not sure if any of this will help but it is at least a starting point.

Comment: Added the failing part of the build output.

Comment: I read over it- nothing stands out.  Short of that identity not having rights to create the folder for whatever reason I don't see anything else.  Assuming you have the tools installed properly- I can't see what the issue is.  Sorry I couldn't help you out here- at this point I would probably troubleshoot it much like you would, deleting the task, moving it to a different part of the build process etc.